# Reading a text file and calculating probability and Shannon's entropy

Tags: python, math, numpy, pandas

I have a text file (tab separated) and I need to calculate the probability and entropy for each column in the text file. Here is what my text file looks like:

```
aaa 0.0520852296    0.1648703511    0.1648703511
bbb 0.1062639955    0.1632039268    0.1632039268
ccc 1.4112745088    4.3654577641    4.3654577641
ddd 0.4992644913    0.1648703511    0.1648703511
eeee    0.169058175 0.1632039268    0.1632039268
```

and so I can calculate the probability using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
f=open(mydata,'r')
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', header=None, names=['val1', 'val2', 'val3']))
print(df)
df.loc[:,"val1":"val3"] = df.loc[:,"val1":"val3"].div(df.sum(axis=0), axis=1)
print(df)
```

which outputs,

```
aaa 0.0232736716    0.0328321936    0.0328321936
bbb 0.0474828153    0.0325003428    0.0325003428
ccc 0.6306113983    0.8693349271    0.8693349271
ddd 0.2230904597    0.0328321936    0.0328321936
eeee    0.0755416551    0.0325003428    0.0325003428
```

And on that output I want to calculate the entropy and gave me the results as output file, and so I have the following code

```
import math
entropy = - sum([ p * math.log(p) / math.log(2.0) for p in df ])
```

But I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: a float is required
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you all

Comment: So in the end you would like to get one entropy per row? Could you provide the expected output?

Comment: Does `import math sum(df.applymap(lambda x: x * math.log(x) / math.log(2.0)).values)` give you what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is with this line

```
entropy = - sum([ p * math.log(p) / math.log(2.0) for p in df ])
```

If you think about (or print out) what `p for p in df` is giving you (e.g. run `print([p for p in df])`), you can see that `p` contains only the headings of the columns.  So you are passing a text label into the `math` functions that expect a `float`.  Hence the error.

[`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) might work well for you here:

```
import math

def shannon(col):
    entropy = - sum([ p * math.log(p) / math.log(2.0) for p in col])
    return entropy

sh_df = df.loc[:,'val1':'val3'].apply(shannon,axis=0)

print(sh_df)
```

---

#### Note

as others have pointed out, you might want to tidy up your dataframe by making column 0 an index - then you won't have to use

```
df.loc[:,'val1':'val3']
```

So you could import your data using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', header=None, index_col=0, names=['val1', 'val2', 'val3'])
```

and avoid the need to use the cumbersome `loc[:,'val1':'val3']` syntax

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you fix your data file instead of trying to do so in python code and reducing the readability. It's as simple as

```
sed 's/ \+/,/g' mydata > my_fixed_data
```

Just run this on the commandline if you are using linux. It will replace all the the spaces with `,`.

*mydata*

```
aaa 0.0520852296    0.1648703511    0.1648703511
bbb 0.1062639955    0.1632039268    0.1632039268
ccc 1.4112745088    4.3654577641    4.3654577641
ddd 0.4992644913    0.1648703511    0.1648703511
eeee    0.169058175 0.1632039268    0.1632039268
```

*my_fixed_data*

```
aaa,0.0520852296,0.1648703511,0.1648703511
bbb,0.1062639955,0.1632039268,0.1632039268
ccc,1.4112745088,4.3654577641,4.3654577641
ddd,0.4992644913,0.1648703511,0.1648703511
eeee,0.169058175,0.1632039268,0.1632039268
```

Then you can simply use the `read_csv` function like

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_fixed_data', header=None, index_col=0, names=['val1', 'val2', 'val3'])
```

Here's what the dataframe now looks like:

```
          val1      val2      val3
aaa   0.052085  0.164870  0.164870
bbb   0.106264  0.163204  0.163204
ccc   1.411275  4.365458  4.365458
ddd   0.499264  0.164870  0.164870
eeee  0.169058  0.163204  0.163204
```

I'm sure there must be equivalents for Windows too. Just google it.

You get the `TypeError: a float is required` error because `for p in df` gives you the column names and not some float values. You may have to fix it accordingly.

```
>>> for p in df:
...     print p
...
val1
val2
val3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
entropy = - sum([ p * math.log(p) / math.log(2.0) for p in df.loc[:,"val1":"val3"] ])
```

PS: Use this to read in your file as data frame:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', header=None, names=['val1', 'val2', 'val3'])
```

Comment: it gives the same error, TypeError: a float is required

Comment: Strange. Because last row worked fine on my computer with model data. Try inspect data types: type df.dtypes.